# Why does a minor faction attack me once I assimilate it?

Tags: endless-legend

I pacified my first minor faction, Bos, by completing their quest. A few turns later I assimilated them. They immediately responded by besieging my city in their native region. What's going on and how am I supposed to respond?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pacifying a minor faction does not affect roaming armies of that faction currently on the map; it only stops new armies from being spawned in that region. You still have to kill off any roaming armies that were spawned before you pacified the faction.

I think it was only coincidence that one of the armies started besieging your city after you assimilated the minor faction.

Comment: Is that a bug? It seems obvious that _pacifying_ a faction means that it will cease to have any military presence.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I would imagine it's a balance issue--if pacifying minor factions gave you control over their roaming armies, it would be easy  to rapidly pacify regions and amass a huge army. That said, Civilization V has a similar mechanic.